# Motorola Droid 4 xt894 won't turn on

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid

Yesterday I charge my phone using USB till this morning, but now it won't show start, i've tried:

- pressing power button >3s
- pressing power and volume down button >10s

but it doesn't work.

when plugged to USB, it still show green light, is there any other button to force restart?

I'm using working Cyanogenmod.

Comment: ah after trying again power and volume down while charging, it works! >__< tG

Comment: So your issue is solved? You might consider to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) then and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was out of power, plugging into USB and wait for a few minutes then press power + vol down for 10 secs to turn it on